# perception_pcl missing libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
When trying to run launch files using the perception_pcl libraries for Fuerte, ROS returns errors  saying that the Segmentation and Feature libraries do not exist in pcl_ros. They were commented out of the CMakeLists.txt file in pcl_ros, but uncommenting and then rebuilding does not work. The library files are still missing. Does anyone know where to get the libraries?
Thank You.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36813/perception_pcl-missing-libraries/) by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2012-06-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem has been fixed. To get the new perception_pcl files, I ran sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-perception-pcl, and the Segmentation and Feature libraries were added as updates.

---

Originally posted by [HITE](https://answers.ros.org/users/2521/hite/) with karma: 92 on 2012-07-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0